# Xamarin ContentPage under Navigation

Tags: android, xamarin

I created a Xamarin Forms app from the Shell project template.

The first page seems to be loaded from App.xaml:

```
<ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate FirstPage}" />
```

If I navigate to any page after that, the title bar / navigation bar seems to cut off or hover over the content:

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage());
```

[image: Xamarin ContentPage under Navigation]

I have tried wrapping the pages in a ScrollView, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just test the sample and I can confirm this issue **has been fixed** in the latest Xamarin.Forms version `4.2.0.848062`.

Please update your `Xamarin.forms` to the latest Version.

You can also see the issue on Github has been closed:

[Shell content layout hides page](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7240) and  [Fix content offset when you navigate to second page on Shell](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/7265)

Comment: Elite. This did the trick. I had version 4.2.0.709249. I first had to update Xamarin Essentials before being able to update Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 1):

I personally think this is an issue with a conflict between Shell and the Application level navigation now while using shell you do not use the Application Navigation what you do is something like what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) mention.

Like for eg you give the ShellContent a Route:

```
 <ShellContent ...
                  Route="defRoute" />
```

Or

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("defRoute", typeof(DefaultPage));
```

And then you navigate something like

```
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("defRoute");
```

For a detailed understanding, I would suggest you check the documentation

Comment: Thanks. I switched over to Shell.Current.GoToAsync("about") after registering the route, but the content is still under the title bar.

Comment: Can you please share your new code and also how you are navigating to the about page? Thanks!

Comment: This can be reproduced if you create a project from the Shell project template and tap on an item to get to the ItemDetailPage, the "Text:" label is underneath the title bar.

Comment: Well, the thing is that it is not reproducing on my end? Are you using the latest XF?

Comment: I was on version 4.2.0.709249 - upgrading to 4.2.0.848062 did the trick, thanks.